# how to read the names of all custom fields in microsoft project?

Tags: c#, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010, psi

I am having trouble finding the local names for custom fields. I tried to use the PSI custom fields service, but no luck. It seems to just get the enterprise fields. I'm really not sure where it is hiding the local names.

I am able to get the custom fields from the ReadProjectDataSet call, but it does not contain the names of the custom fields.

here is my code, which I think was copied from the projtool sample:

```
 public static SvcCustomFields.CustomFieldDataSet ReadCustomFields( )
    {
        CheckAccess();

        using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(projectClient.InnerChannel))
        {
            ProjectAuthentication.UseCorrectHeaders(isImpersonated);

            return customFieldsClient.ReadCustomFields(string.Empty, false);
       }
    }
```

here is a screenshot of how it is appearing project desktop:

[image]

Comment: You may get "recommended" names - the names are defined on PWA for the columns, but the users can give their own labels to any column in Project Pro and the labels are local for Tables I guess. I don't think there is a way to read tables definition through PSI - that is all binary things for Project Pro only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is like this:

```
CustomFieldDataSet cfDS = new CustomFieldDataSet();

PSLibrary.Filter cfFilter = new Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library.Filter();
cfFilter.FilterTableName = cfDS.CustomFields.TableName;

cfFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(cfDS.CustomFields.TableName, cfDS.CustomFields.MD_PROP_NAMEColumn.ColumnName));
cfFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(cfDS.CustomFields.TableName, cfDS.CustomFields.MD_PROP_IDColumn.ColumnName));
cfFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(cfDS.CustomFields.TableName, cfDS.CustomFields.MD_PROP_UIDColumn.ColumnName));
cfFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(cfDS.CustomFields.TableName, cfDS.CustomFields.MD_LOOKUP_TABLE_UIDColumn.ColumnName));
cfFilter.Fields.Add(new PSLibrary.Filter.Field(cfDS.CustomFields.TableName, cfDS.CustomFields.MD_PROP_TYPE_ENUMColumn.ColumnName));

cfDS = ReadCustomFields(cfFilter.GetXml(), false);
```

The sample was written as addition to CustomFieldsClient. It reads Name of a custom field, ID, UID, UID of Lookup table and Type of the field.

But it only reads name of the fields. There are user defined labels for the fields and the labels are defined in Project Pro and stored in Table definitions which are available through Project Pro only.

Comment: okay...so you are saying I can't get the labels I applied to the custom fields in project pro? so let's say I added a custom field column and typed a name like 'test custom field', you are saying I can't get that, right?

Comment: My answer depends on where you "typed" the name. If you typed it in PWA when you define the field then the name can be queried using the code I put. But if you typed the name as Label in Project Pro - then you can get it using Project Pro